# Is the asp.net mvc 5 sample project with 2 factor authentication a sample or production ready?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

It seems like the only way I can currently get 2 factor authentication from identity 2 is if I create an empty MVC 5 app then install the Identity samples Pre release with the package manager like so:

```
Install-Package -Prerelease Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples
```

But it seems like this is only a sample and not something I can use for a real app? Can I use this "sample" project as a real app? It says in the documentation at www.asp.net/identity that it is a production release!

I just want to get 2 factor authentication into a project and I'm not sure how to do it? All the guides online show the use of the prerelease sample project from NuGet. I guess the question is - is this sample project ready for the "Show" or should I wait for a project template in VS 2013 to show up in some update? I'm afraid that if I create a MVC 5 app now with no 2 factor authentication and then try and add it later it will be a pain in the ars! Or if I use the sample project with 2FA now it might have major bugs that will be a pain in the ars later to fix being that its just a sample app.

Last question! If I do end up using the sample app to create a 2FA in my app can I still register with Facebook/Google/Twitter/etc for login?

Comment: You are asking if the samples are production code or... samples?

Answer (score 1):

The samples are showing how you can enable 2FA and more features of Identity. They have some areas which are not production ready such as the WebAdmin scenario of managing users and roles. We are updating the project templates in next update of Visual Studio 2013 which will have 2FA enabled in the templates. The project templates are based on the samples so will be pretty close in terms of content.
You can also use Facebook/ Twitter etc for logging in in the samples package