# Is the authentication system in the ASP.NET 4.5.2 MVC project template suitable for use in a real world application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

If I create an ASP.NET MVC project using [this project type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SluS4.png), the project includes an authentication system supporting two-factor authentication and user management. Is this system suitable for use in production code with changes made to make it suit the target application? I'll probably end up removing a lot of the code dealing with signing in via Facebook and such.

I found [this pre-existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299819/is-the-asp-net-mvc-5-sample-project-with-2-factor-authentication-a-sample-or-pro) regarding a similar issue, but it seems to refer to a pre-release version of the project template rather than the current version, which seems to have been altered since. Setting up authentication in MVC seems to involve a large amount of mundane boilerplate and I'd prefer to use something that has already been tried and tested, rather than try to roll my own and introduce security holes in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. I use the Identity Framework in a number of production applications and it works well. All of the stuff that's included in the template is a great start to take care of the boilerplate you're talking about, and with a few tweaks for your particular purposes it can be a really simple but robust solution that takes almost no time at all to implement.